# Athena Partition s3 access logs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Not like ELB logs, S3 access logs files are not structured with folders

Here is an examle:

`BUCKET_NAME/ACCESS_LOGS_DEST/2018-03-15-03-05-46-2E5105C8E00951B32018-03-15-03-05-46-2E5105C8E00951B3`

Is there a simple way to partition them in Athena based on day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athena would not be able to partition your data by day using the S3 keys you describe.  Athena's partitioning is based on S3 "directories", such that Athena can find, read, or ignore a partition by distinct S3 locations.

In [Partitioning Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html), there are some examples of partitioning schemes that illustrate the use of directories.